# Need Help Getting New Line When Writing to File

Tags: c++, filestream, fstream, ofstream

I have the endl, but its not going into my file, so when I enter in more than 1 line, its all on the same line in the notepad.

I've tried:

codeFile << codeLine;
codeFile << endl;

I've also tried adding a "\n" to the string by adding a constant string to it but it doesn't work.

```
//Writing Coded Lines to File:
        if(codeFile)
        {
            //Relaying Feedback to User:
            cout << "File has been successfully opened/created" << endl;
            cout << "\nWriting to file..." << endl;

            for(int i = 0; i < lines; i++)
            {
                //Getting Non-Coded Line from User:
                cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
                cin.getline(line, length);

                //Creating Copy of Line:
                strcpy(cline, line);

                //Gathering Line Length:
                length = strlen(line);

                //Coding Line:
                codedLine = code(length, line, cline, sAlphabet);

                //Coded Line Test
                cout << codedLine;

                //Writing to File:
                codeFile << codedLine << endl;
            }
        }

        //Closing File:
        codeFile.close();

        cout << "\nFile has now been closed";
    }
```

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be using cygwn would you?

Comment: If you talk about Windows notepad.exe that only breaks lines at "\r\n" but that's a visual thing related to the application. Your new line character is still present. Also, don't use std::endl, use '\n' instead.

Comment: I am using cygwin. But I'll try that.

Comment: It worked, thank you! "/r/n"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cygwin mocks a POSIX system and uses Unix line endings, not the Windows line endings understood by NotePad.

Replacing `endl` with `'\n'` won't help. `endl` is a `'\n'` followed by a stream flush.

The best option is to use a different file reader, WordPad for example, that understands Unix line endings. The alternatives are to

- Change your compiler toolchain to one that is not emulating a POSIX operating system, or
- Brute force a Windows line ending with `\r\n`, but this means your code will have a similar wrong line-ending problem on a Unix -based system.